# Mocking the health endpoint for a service

Tags: mocking, karate

I am trying to run a connectivity test using Karate. The microservice under test checks the status from the health end point and acts if the status returned is not as expected. I have the microservice running in my local:8080. The health end point also runs in local:8080/health. I need to mock the health end point response to return a DOWN status. But since the actual micro service is running in 8080, I am not able to run the mock in 8080. Has anybody faced the same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the port used by the mocks, please refer the docs !

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty

EDIT: from the comments, if you can configure the calling app to use a proxy server, you can use Karate. See option (5a) in the diagram below the picture here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example

Comment: I understand that. So, mock running in 8081 and service under test running in 8080. Since the service under test is running in 8080, the health end point which need to be mocked also runs in 8080. I dont have an option in the application to change the health end point to listen to 8081 where the mock is running.

Comment: @sindhu okay got it, Karate can't do that magic, sorry :) use docker or change the application config, all the best ;)

Comment: @Sindhu -- there are API simulation tools that can do what you are looking for. They can be called as a proxy: the responses to recognized requests are simulated; unmatched requests are forwarded to the actual live API and the responses are relayed back to the calling API client. (disclaimer: I am involved with one such tool)

Comment: @apisim - nice try, but if she wants two apps to use the same port on the same node, I think that's impossible :)

Comment: yeh, sort of 2 endpoints listening to the same port. Dream come true :)

Comment: Think of it as a proxy in front of live APIs...because it is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Start the simulator on, say, port 8888; then configure the calling app to use the simulator as HTTP/S proxy on port 8888. As a proxy, the simulator will get all requests sent by the app, even to different backend HTTP/S APIs, same port or not. If a request is matched (e.g. host=localhost, port=8080, uri=/health) then a simulated response is returned; otherwise, the simulator will forward the unmatched request to its actual destination and send back the response. It is real,it works :) HTH

Comment: @apisim got it, you are assuming that she can configure the calling app to respect system proxy settings. in that case karate will work - look at (5a) in the table below the picture: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#consumer-provider-example HTH ;)

Comment: Thanks @apisim. That looks like a solution. Trying it now with Karate.